# Redirecting marked packets to Tun device

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, tunnel

I have a small program that needs to do various things with a selection of packets, based on various iptable rules. The packets are `MARK`ed this way:

```
iptables -t mangle -d 10.10.0.0/16 -j MARK --set-mark 4
iptables -t mangle -d 10.11.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 5
iptables -t mangle -d 10.0.0.1     -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

I also have a Tun device named `maintun` that a userspace process is doing some I/O on.

How do I go about ensuring that the affected packets are sent to/via the `maintun`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use **policy routing**.

First you mark some packets,

```
 iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -d 10.0.0.1 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

then you create a new routing table, call it *TunRoutTable*:

```
 echo 201 TunRoutTable >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

then you tell your pc to use table TunRoutTable for packets marked *1*:

```
 ip rule add fwmark 1 table TunRoutTable
```

and now you provide a default gateway for the new routing table:

```
 ip route add default via XXX.YYY.WWW.ZZZ dev tun0 table TunRoutTable
```

where XXX.YY.WWW.ZZZ is the ip address (in the usual dotted quad notation) of your gateway on the Tun0 interface.

Comment: Thanks! Is `ip rule` and `ip route` guaranteed to work on "all" distros that support iptables? It is preferable for me to try to keep it in iptables if not. It is likely that I will need to run this on a variety of distros, ranging from Arch to Centos.

Comment: the ip command is part of the iproute2 suite which is either installed by default, or may be downloaded through your distro package manager. Keep in mind that iproute2 is the **new** standard networking utility,and has superseded all previous utilities such as ifconfig, netstat, and so on.

Comment: Alright, so provided that it's a recent release, it is most likely included under iproute2. It would seem I need to get with the times, heh.