# Check for packets MARKed by iptables

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, tcpdump

I am marking TCP and UDP packets in order to send them to two different interfaces (say wlan0 and eth0), I did this by following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/919300).

Assuming this configuration:

```
eth0 address:  192.168.0.84 

wlan0 address: 192.168.1.22
```

I am setting the following rules/routes:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark 1
echo 201 routeTcp >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 1 table routeTcp
ip route add default via 192.168.0.0 dev eth0 table routeTcp

iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp -j MARK --set-mark 2
echo 202 routeUdp >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 2 table routeUdp
ip route add default via 192.168.1.0 dev wlan0 table routeUdp
```

---

`route -n` output:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

---

`ip route show` output:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.84  metric 1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.22  metric 9
```

---

`ip route show table routeUdp`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

---

`ip route show table routeTcp`:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

---

`iptables -nL -v --line-numbers -t mangle` output:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 388K packets, 474M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     360K  464M MARK       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK set 0x1
2    27269   11M MARK       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK set 0x2

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 385K packets, 474M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 290K packets, 33M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 290K packets, 33M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

How can I check that the packets are actually being sent by the right interface?

I've been struggling with tcpdump with no success.

Thank you guys.

Comment: `ip route` and `iptables -S -t mangle` would be better. Also, how did you use tcpdump?

Comment: Well, i did use tcpdump to monitor eth0 / wlan0 traffic, in order to see if TCP and UDP is going on the expected interface.

Comment: Pls do not use route -n to display the routing table, it is an obsolete command. Use instead *ip route show table name1** or whatever your routing table is called. If you do not specify a name, it will display the default routing table.

Comment: added ip route show output...

Comment: The UDP packets whch show up thru eth0, are they directed to your LAN or to the Internet at large?

Comment: Two of them are google ips (chrome) and one is from microsoft (probably skype)

Comment: Are you by any chance using iptables with MASQUERADE or SNAT?

Comment: Umh... I did not set any of them, I am just using the iptables commands above. Which one should I use ? 

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I am starting to suspect some kernel module may be not loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29543/discussion-between-giancarlo-and-mariusmatutiae).

Answer (score 1):

Probably, they are not: your routing commands are wrong: you use

```
   ip route add default via 192.168.0.0 dev eth0 table routeTcp
   ip route add default via 192.168.1.0 dev wlan0 table routeUdp
```

while they should be

```
   ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table routeTcp
   ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 table routeUdp
```

**if** your gateways are 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1, respectively; if not, pls adjust accordingly.

As for checking,

```
     tcpdump -i eth0 -n udp
```

in one terminal, and

```
     tcpdump -i wlan0 -n tcp
```

in another terminal; they should **both** return **no** crossing packets.

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot we need to distinguish between incoming and outgoing packets, only the outgoing ones are segregated.  Pls use

```
       tcpdump -i wlan0 -n tcp and src host The_IP_ADDRESS_of_Wlan0
       tcpdump -i eth0 -n udp and src host The_IP_ADDRESS_of_eth00
```

Comment: well...  you *almost* made my day... I see no TCP packets on wlan but I can still see some UDP packets on eth. 
Adding gateways does not change the situation: http://pastebin.com/pyRXRFmX

Comment: @Giancarlo incoming or outgoing?  pls read my edit

Comment: Ops, I forgot to say outgoing... I am gonna test it again after a reboot ;)

Comment: Nothing to do... 
eth0:   lots of UDP (NOK), all the TCP(OK)
wlan0 just some UDP (NOK, just five packets) and no TCP (OK)